# Web-based Circular Interface Frontend - No Graphics!

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, html, web-frontend

How would you create the front-end for a *web-based* circular interface that *does not involve using graphic files* or Flash?

Comment: What do you mean with circular interface?

Comment: I have never, ever before seen the term "web-based circular interface".

Comment: most interfaces are rectangular (think: windows)... circular interface is... circular. you can't easily code circular div's, but circular boxes are a cinch, so creating stuff with box-like interfaces are already "built-in" - you can just jQuery assign `(".box").click()` to activate some function when a particular div is clicked for example - but can't do that with a circle

Comment: Hence SVG/VML - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be looking for a [radial menu / pie menu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_menu) ?

Check this Example out: http://www.tikku.com/scripts/ui/radmenu/radmenu_example.html

The plugin page is here: http://www.tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin

Comment: this is really neat! - looks like it'd scale and work for more complicated things... even multi-layer target-looking piemenu's!

Answer (score 3):

I would probably go with something like this: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: yes but raphaeljs is like processing.js - very neat graphical stuff but overkill for a nav menu!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind it not being IE compatible... You could use CSS3 border-radius to round the corners of a div.

But my general answer to your question is that I wouldn't.  I'd ask why the constraints and explain that at least some images are probably required.